# Better way to define role restrictions in the database tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

Role table

```
RoleID Desc
1      primary
2      secondary
3      alternate
```

Users

```
UserID  Name
1       ann
2       saylor
3       jim
4       ken
5       kathy
```

Route table

```
RouteID   Name
1          x
2          y
```

RouteRoleUser table

```
RouteID   RoleID      UserID
1         primary      ann
1         secondary    saylor
1         alternate    jim
1         alternate    ken
1         alternate    kathy
```

I have a grid which shows the following:

```
Route | Primary Pumper | Secondary Pumper | Alternate Pumpers (comma separated)
x        ann                saylor           jim, ken, kathy
```

My requirements are:

- Any route can have only one primary user
- Any route can have 0 or one secondary user
- Any route can have 0 or more alternate users
- All users of a route are unique

How can I have the requirements restriction from a db design perspective in the RouteRoleUser table? Currently if I make Route, Role and User as candidate key, it does not
stop anyone to add two primary users for a route.

Is there a better way?

Comment: When you say you have a grid which shows those sample data, that means you have a query which populates it from the 3 tables? +1 for the question

Comment: yes right now it populates from 3 tables + 1. I will modify and pull the RouteRoleUser table up in the question.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals: Route is a path a sales person takes.

Answer (score 1):

For the "Any route can have *N* number of *(type)* user(s)" rule, you could validate this by using an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger and preventing the insert. I personally handle this type of logic at the application or stored procedure level.

For the "All users of a route are unique" you can enforce this with a UNIQUE constraint on RouteID, UserID.